# How can I create external node WAS 8.5.5.x

Tags: websphere

I have two machines. On both I have WAS 8.5.5.x ND. So I want create on Computer1 an app server and on Computer2 a cluster for this server.

I've created on Computer1 Development manager(Dmgr01), nodeagent(node - hostnameNode01, cell - hostnameCell01) and server (mysrv at the same cell and node). And it works fine. But how can I create an external node/custom profile with another host(Computer2 hostname) to create a cluster for hostnameCell01 on Computer2 using Dmgr01?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a standalone application server on computer2, and follow these steps to federate it into the cell: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tagt_svr_conf_nodes.html They'll show you how to use the administrative console on the deployment manager to add the new node.

If you want to do it from computer2 instead, you can use the addNode command: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_addnode.html If you go that route, make sure when you create the standalone application server profile that you give it a *different* cell name than the cell you actually intend it to be federated to. There's a list of best practices for addNode here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_nodetips.html